# generate id for self referencing table hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, db2

Hi I have a table on DB2 database as follows:

id (PKey)
doc_id(FKey pointing to id) not null

This is a strange legacy table that I cannot change. I cannot write/modify triggers either.

I am trying to create a hibernate mapping for this table but I can't figure out how to write this odd relationship.

I have two options:
1- tell Hibernate to leave id and doc_id as null then a trigger will set the values for me.

2- figure out a way to tell hibernate to use the sequence to set the values for both values at once.

I cannot seem to find a way to tell hibernate to do this?

any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">SQ_DCMNT</param>
        </generator>
</id>

<property name="packageDcmntId" generated="insert">
        <column name="PACKAGE_DCMNT_ID" not-null="true"/>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would configure this entity to use a custom subclass of `SequenceGenerator` or `SequenceHiLoGenerator` to generate its ID. This custom subclass would override the generate method like this:

```
@Override
public Serializable generate(final SessionImplementor session, Object obj) {
    Serializable result = super.generate(session, obj);
    ((MyBizarreEntity) obj).setPackageDcmntId((Long) result);
    return result;
}
```

This way, the entity's property will automatically have the value of the generated ID, before the insert is made, which is necessary since the column has a not null constraint.

I've not tested it, but it should work.

Or you could just use a regular sequence generator for the ID, make sure that the access type is *property* and not *field*, and implement the `setId` method like this:

```
/**
 * Sets the ID as well as the packageDcmntId, since they share the same value
 */
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.packageDcmntId = id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but that's a bit of a hack and bounds the generator to the entity which isn't ideal.

Comment: Having such a bad database design is not ideal, and I doubt you'll find a clean solution instead of a hack for such a thing. You might make the generator more configurable, by making it use reflection to access the property, etc., but I hope you don't have more than one table like this in your schema. If I'm right, then keep it simple, and just hardcode the entity. If you change it, it will even be detected at compile-time. The other solution is to generate and assign the ID manually by calling the sequence yourself, and make the setId change the other field value at the same time.

Comment: Additional comment: If the access type is property, the sequence generator should call the setId method. If this method also changes the other field, the problem is solved. No need of a custom generator.

Comment: what about <sql-insert></sql-insert> in hbm file? can I use that somehow to insert the object?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last comment please?

Comment: I doubt it. How would you refer to the non-existing row's ID to insert the value of the PackageDcmntId: insert into foo (id, bar, PackageDcmntId) values(?, ?, *what*)

Comment: Hibernate populates your entities. It can access its fields directly (bypassing the setters): that's the field access type. The property access type consists in populating your entity by calling setters. I suppose that if the access type is property, the ID generator will set the ID of your entity by calling its setter method: setId(Long id). If this setter sets the ID value and also the packageDcmntId value (their value is the same), then your problem is solved. Just use a regular sequence generator and make sure the access type is property. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you sir. I used the access property to set the id and it worked....thanks a lot!

Comment: actually it doesn't work. while both values are set to the same values using the method you suggested...at insertion time, database tries to check foreign key constraint on PACKAGE_DCMNT_ID, it fails because the row itself hasn't been inserted.

Comment: How do you do to insert a row manually, without Hibernate? It starts looking like an unsolvable chicken and egg problem. Couldn't you make this foreign key constraint deferred?

Comment: sorry i was violating other constraints and i didn't realize..your solution did work...my bad...thanks again for your help